# Is there a pattern for dealing with "Cancel" in AngularJS modal dialogs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Note: This is not about showing a modal dialog with AngularJS, that topic has plenty of questions and answers!

This question is about how to react to both OK and Cancel within a modal dialog on a page. Let's say you've got a scope with just one variable in it:

```
$scope.description = "Oh, how I love porcupines..."
```

If I provide you with a modal dialog on the page and use ng-model="description" within that dialog, all of the changes you make are actually made in real time to the description itself as you type. That's bad, because then how do you cancel out of that dialog?

There's this question that says to do what I explain below. The accepted answer for it is the same "solution" I came up with: [AngularJS: Data-bound modal - save changes only when "Save" is clicked, or forget changes if "Cancel" is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792077/angularjs-data-bound-modal-save-changes-only-when-save-is-clicked-or-forge)

I can see how to do it if clicking the button to bring up a modal goes back to a function in the back and that creates a temporary copy of the relevant data for the modal and then pops up the modal. Then "OK" (or "Save" or whatever) could copy the temporary values to the actual model values.

main.js (excerpt):

```
$scope.descriptionUncommitted = $scope.description;

$scope.commitChanges = function () {
  $scope.description = $scope.descriptionUncommitted;
}
```

main.html (excerpt):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="descriptionUncommitted"/>

<button ng-click="commitChanges()">Save</button>
```

The problem with that is **it's not declarative**! In fact, it's nothing like AngularJS anywhere else. It's almost as though we need an ng-model-uncommitted="description" where they could make all the changes they want but they only get committed when we trigger with another declaration. Is there such a thing in a plugin somewhere or is AngularJS itself adding it?

**Edit: It seems that an example of a different way of doing it might be in order.**

main.js:

```
$scope.filename = "panorama.jpg";
$scope.description = "A panorama of the mountains.";

$scope.persist = function () { // Some function to hit a back end service. };
```

main.html:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model-uncommitted="filename"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model-uncommitted="description"/>

  <button ng-commit ng-click="persist()">Save</button>
  <button ng-discard>Cancel</button>
</form>
```

I stuck a form tag around it because I don't know how you would group the items so it was clear it was all part of the same "transaction" (for lack of a better word). But there would need to be some way that this could all happen automatically and the cloned copies of the model variables are used for initial values, used for input and updated automatically, validated, etc. and then finally discarded or copied to the same value that initially was used to create them if the user decides to commit.

Isn't something like this easier than code in the controller to do that work over and over again for 20 modals in a big website? Or am I nuts?

Comment: Are you looking for a cancel button that automatically reverts changes to a model made in a modal?  How about refreshing the model when the cancel button is clicked so the model will be overwritten without the need for additional temporary variables?  Can you provide an example of the syntax/mark-up you are looking for.

Comment: You can't get away with allowing the changes to occur because the user might literally see an instance of {{description}} on the page updating as they type (or values recalculating in the case of a number, etc.). I'll add to the above to provide some ideas for what I'd like to see. I was just hoping something already existed.

Comment: You're definitely not nuts. I'm not clear on description and altDescription. Are they two separate models and not your version of a backup? And in your example, what would those fields show? The edited or unedited data?

Comment: Giving this a little more thought, I'm pretty sure you can accomplish what you want in a directive.

Comment: I've tried to make it clearer that the values are unrelated, I just wanted to show that this should work even when there are multiple model values. I expect that you'd bring up the page and you'd see the inputs filled with the current values for filename and description. After editing them if the user hits "Save" those changes are pushed into the model variables just as if you had used ng-model for each one and the ng-click could trigger something to push that on to a back end service if so desired. If the user hits cancel then those changes are discarded and the model values never changed.

Comment: Take a look at gargc's answer below.  I was going to present pretty much the same approach. A directive is what you want. It has shared and isolate scope, so you can handle everything there.

Comment: I'm running into pretty much the same situation today.  Did you come up with a good solution?

Comment: @EricB. For the most part yes, but it may not be exactly what will suit you. We use Bootstrap for our UI and we use AngularUI Bootstrap as a wrapper. When you use their Modal code, it uses a separate controller and separate $scope for the dialog boxes. Thus there is a clear separation between the two and you never end up with the modal stepping upon the original values. It's a very clean way of dealing with it and we liked it a lot.

Comment: I'm actually using the same technology, but trying to leverage the $rollbackViewValue() in Angular 1.3.0 to be able to seamlessly integrate the two.  I find Using an isolated scope for the modal is a little impractical.  Otherwise you have to return the updated value from the close method which I find a little clunky.  Unless you have found a cleaner way to use it.  Do you have a code snippet that you can share how you have integrated the two, including the callbacks on success/failure?

Comment: @JohnMunsch The more I play around with this, the more I find that there is no way to avoid creating a copy in the modal's scope and then upon success, copy the modal's scoped value back to my original object.  Which I find very cludgy as an approach.  Are you able to show what you did to avoid that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically, in angular if something is not declarative, you make a **directive**.

```
 .directive('shadow', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      target: '=shadow'            
    },
    link: function(scope, el, att) {
      scope[att.shadow] = angular.copy(scope.target);

      scope.commit = function() {
        scope.target = scope[att.shadow];
      };
    }
  };
```

Then:

```
  <div shadow="data">
    <input ng-model="data">
    <button ng-click="commit()">save</button>
  </div>
```

So `data` inside the `shadow` directive will be a **copy** of the original `data`.
And it will be copied back to the original when the button is clicked.

And here is working example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/odedex/5/edit)

I've not tested it beyond this example, so it may not work in other cases, but I think it gives an idea of the possibilites.

**Edit:**

Another example with an object instead of a string, and several fields in the form (an additional `angular.copy` is required here): [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/quvuwosipuxe/1/edit)

**Edit2, angular versions 1.2.x**

As per this [change](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7), 
the `input` inside the directive is not accessing the isolated scope anymore. One alternative is creating a non-isolated child scope (`scope:true`), to hold the copy of the data and accessing the parent scope for saving it.

So for later versions of angular, this is the same approach as before slightly modified to do the trick:

```
.directive('shadow', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, el, att) {
      scope[att.shadow] = angular.copy(scope[att.shadow]);

      scope.commit = function() {
        scope.$parent[att.shadow] = angular.copy(scope[att.shadow]);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jifodaxexodo/1/edit)

Note that the problem with using `$parent`, is that it may break if eventually there is another scope in the middle.

Comment: That's very interesting. I haven't done my first directives yet so this will be a perfect opportunity to start.

Comment: I really like this approach for doing Save's on individual fields of on a modal form. But I have a problem when the expressions for the 'ng-modal' and 'shadow' attributes are more than just simple scalar values. How do you modify the directive to work with data in the scope that is hierarchical? I am setting the scope to an object that has many nested properties and arrays and want to use this directive at various nested properties within that hierarchy. But the current directive assumes scalar values.

Comment: @JezzSantos It should work with an object, just add an additional `angular.copy` when copying back to the original scope (to avoid holding a reference to the same object). Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/quvuwosipuxe/1/edit)

Comment: Why does it only work with angular 1.0.5, if you change to later versions the parent scope is immediately changed

Comment: @RuiGonçalves True, something about isolated scopes changed in newer versions (perhaps [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7)?). I've updated the answer with another alternative, I don't really like the $parent stuff, but at least works.

Comment: Awesome. Just dumped it in my project and it worked!

Comment: What if u use controller-as syntax, which is the new way to go since 2.0 will remove $scope?

Comment: This doesn't work with `ng-repeat` nested within this directive if you are using dot notation for your scope variables. For some reason, when Angular resolves the `ng-repeat` expression, it resolves the dot notation against the parent scope instead of the directive's child scope. See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dahoqikezo/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 21):

As of Angular 1.3 there is [ngModelOptions](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) directive that allows to achive the same behaviour natively.

```
<form name="userForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" name="userName">
    <button type="submit">save</button>
    <button type="button"  ng-click="userForm.userName.$rollbackViewValue();">cancel</button>
</form>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8btk5/104/

Comment: Submit buttons don't work in ng-form, so how would I tell the model to update only when a specific button (not submit) is pressed?

Comment: Submit does work for ng-form, just add an ng-submit="..." attribute to the form tag, and when the submit button is clicked it will be executed.  However, one issue with this solution is that you cannot do live validation, as the validation isn't triggered because the change isn't committed until the form is submitted.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Don't use all those 'Copying'. Just learn how to use `ng-model` correctly

Comment: Worth noting that you can also use `ng-model-options` and `$rollbackViewValue()` on the form directly in case of multiple fields.

Comment: This is good. However, keep in mind that with hitting submit the model is updated. This poses an issue if you transfer the data to the server and the request returns with an error. The user might want to cancel now, but you cannot roll the view value back.

If anyone has an idea about that issue, let me know. Until then I'll have to stick with copying. :-(

Answer (score 11):

Facing the same problem and going though this thread I came up with `lazy-model` directive that works exactly like `ng-model` but saves changes only **when form was submitted**.

Usage:

```
<input type="text" lazy-model="user.name">
```

Please note to wrap it into `<form>` tag otherwise lazy model will not know when to push changes to original model.

**Full working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/8btk5/3/

lazyModel directive code:
(better use [actual version on github](https://github.com/vitalets/lazy-model))

```
app.directive('lazyModel', function($parse, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',  
    require: '^form',
    scope: true,
    compile: function compile(elem, attr) {
        // getter and setter for original model
        var ngModelGet = $parse(attr.lazyModel);
        var ngModelSet = ngModelGet.assign;  
        // set ng-model to buffer in isolate scope
        elem.attr('ng-model', 'buffer');
        // remove lazy-model attribute to exclude recursion
        elem.removeAttr("lazy-model");
        return function postLink(scope, elem, attr) {
          // initialize buffer value as copy of original model 
          scope.buffer = ngModelGet(scope.$parent);
          // compile element with ng-model directive poining to buffer value   
          $compile(elem)(scope);
          // bind form submit to write back final value from buffer
          var form = elem.parent();
          while(form[0].tagName !== 'FORM') {
            form = form.parent();
          }
          form.bind('submit', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModelSet(scope.$parent, scope.buffer);
            });
         });
         form.bind('reset', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.buffer = ngModelGet(scope.$parent);
            });
         });
        };  
     }
  };
});
```

[Actual source code on GitHub](https://github.com/vitalets/lazy-model)

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be over-thinking this. There isn't a plug-in because the process is pretty simple. If you want a pristine copy of the model, make one and keep it in the controller. If a user cancels, reset the model to your copy and use the FormController.$setPristine() method to make the form pristine again.

```
//Controller:

myService.findOne({$route.current.params['id']}, function(results) {
    $scope.myModel = results;
    var backup = results;
}

//cancel
$scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.myModel = backup;
    $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<form name="myForm">
```

You need to name the form to create the $scope.myForm controller.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I said I didn't want to do because it's the opposite of a declarative solution. It's what we have to do at the moment but it's making the controller get all up in the face of the HTML/UI rather than simply acting as a keeper for business logic and the client side copy of the model.

Comment: I'm not following your "controller all up in the face" part. The copy remains in the controller. It isn't touching the view, just resetting the model, no different than setting it in the first place. Would you envision a directive on each ng-model field? Or maybe you were thinking that Angular could keep a shadow copy of the model on its own? The second approach sounds interesting.

Comment: OK, check out the example I added and see if that makes any more sense.

Comment: What is the value/purpose of `$setPristine()`?  How does that help?  Do you know if there is a way to use the new method `$rollbackViewValue()` in Angular 1.3.0 to avoid the storing of a copy?

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to copy the model before editing it, and on cancel, restore the original. Angular Controller Code:

```js
//on edit, make a copy of the original model and store it on scope
function edit(model){
  //put model on scope for the cancel method to access
  $scope.modelBeingEdited = model;
  //copy from model -> scope.originalModel
  angular.copy(model,$scope.originalModel);  
}

function cancelEdit(){
  //copy from scope.original back to your model 
  angular.copy($scope.originalModel, $scope.modelBeingEdited)  
}
```

So on open of the modal dialog, call the edit function and pass a pointer to the model you want to edit.
Then make sure your modal dialog is bound to $scope.editingModel.
On cancel, call the cancel function, and it will copy the original values back.

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Please see sharondios answer above for a better version of this concept - as you dont need to store the original model on the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try at keeping it simple, making it declarative and not dependent on form tags or other stuff.

A simple directive:

```
.directive("myDirective", function(){
return {
  scope: {
    item: "=myDirective"
  },
  link: function($scope){
    $scope.stateEnum = {
      view: 0, 
      edit: 1
    };

    $scope.state = $scope.stateEnum.view;

    $scope.edit = function(){
      $scope.tmp1 = $scope.item.text;
      $scope.tmp2 = $scope.item.description;
      $scope.state = $scope.stateEnum.edit;
    };

    $scope.save = function(){
      $scope.item.text = $scope.tmp1;
      $scope.item.description = $scope.tmp2;
      $scope.state = $scope.stateEnum.view;
    };

    $scope.cancel = function(){
      $scope.state = $scope.stateEnum.view;
    };
  },
  templateUrl: "viewTemplate.html"
};
})
```

viewTemplate.html:

```
<div>
  <span ng-show="state == stateEnum.view" ng-click="edit()">{{item.text}}, {{item.description}}</span>
  <div ng-show="state == stateEnum.edit"><input ng-model="tmp1" type="text"/> <input ng-model="tmp2" type="text"/><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="save()">save</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="cancel()">cancel</a></div>
</div>
```

Then set the context (item):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myItems">
  <div my-directive="item"></div>
</div>
```

See it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/VqoKQoIyhtYnge2hzrFk?p=preview