# angularJS one way data binding and model edit with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In my app i use modal form to edit table view data. And i have one trouble, on first steps i didn't use some other variable and .copy() - so that when i edit my data - in table i didn't see any edit's until i click on save (so now it's reference). Now i need to do what i have describen before...

And i see that angularJS 1.3 add one feature as: one way data binding.

Could i somehow use it in my app?

i have written a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/4gAWiK5gVg58jWtwYovK?p=preview

and code:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.4" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="ArticleCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <ol >
      <li ng-repeat="item in articles">
        <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
        <h2>{{::item.age}}</h2> <!--(like this i wanna to use with angularJS 1.3)-->
        <a ng-click="editArticle(item)"> - Edit - </a>
      </li>
    </ol>
    Edit your title: <input type="text" ng-model="article.name"/>
    Edit your age: <input type="text" ng-model="article.age"/>
    <p>And save:</p>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

and js:

```
var app = angular
    .module('myapp', []);

angular.module('myapp')
  .controller('ArticleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.articles = [{name: '123', age: 10}, {name: '456', age: 20}, {name: '789', age: 30}];
    $scope.article = {name: '', age: ''};
    $scope.editArticle = function(article){
      $scope.article = article;
    };
  }])
```

if something is not clear, please write it in comments. Thank you.

Also one more time and shortly: do not update model in ng-repeat until button "save" is clicked.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to use the .copy() approach to delay applying model changes? You cannot use one way data binding to do what you are describing. That is only used to populate data into the dom once and then never change it again. Copying your model object is the only way to do what you are describing.

Comment: @jw56578 yes - with copy i need to rewrite code almost from zero... 
also: maybe there are pocibilities to change ng-repeat array item after update of one item?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838148/is-there-a-pattern-for-dealing-with-cancel-in-angularjs-modal-dialogs

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've already found a way to solve your problem.

As proposed in the comments you need to copy the model object and at saving you can re-apply the new data to the model.

This is the solution I found with the following changes:

```
$scope.editArticle = function(article){
      edit_article = article; // edit_article stores a reference to the article to edit
      angular.copy(article, $scope.article); // copy article to form fields --> ref. by $scope.article
};
$scope.saveArticle = function(){
      update(edit_article, $scope.article); // dest. is stored reference to element in list
                                            // source is the new input
      //console.log('edited value', $scope.article);
};
```

**Short explanation:** I'm storing a reference to the article in `edit_article`, because `angular.copy` is removing the `$$hashKey` from the copy and angular can't locate the position in the array with-out the hash.
Once save is clicked the update function will change the saved article to the newly entered data.

I have found a useful [blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2443-rendering-dom-elements-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm) where I took the update function from.

You can find the updated plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LRQyeiK7gDN2ifxoYUHa?p=preview).

Comment: your answer is good, but in my case it's to hard to change: a lot of logic is there...

Comment: something is unclear with update in table... how to update value in table?

Comment: What do you mean with table? Do you mean the values used in ng-repeat? Please show some more code in a demo jsfiddle and I could try to help.